# Button incrementing from 0 to 9 and repeating

Tags: c#

I have to create a button which counts from 0 to 9, and after 9 come 0 again. One of my friends said that this code is not good enough. Can you explain to me why it's a problem to use `-1`?

```
int szám = 0;
private void counterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    szám++;
    this.Text = szám.ToString();
    if (szám == 9)
    {
        szám = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: szám? not very clear what is it

Comment: it's just a simple variable. It means number in hungarian.

Comment: I recommend to use only ASCII characters in source code, because some tools bay have problems with unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem with the -1 is that it's a bit harder to follow what the code is doing.

You are doing half of an operation by setting the variable to -1, and the operation is only completed when the event handler is called again and the value is increased to 0. By splitting the operation over two executions of the event handler, you have to think two steps further to understand what the code actually does.

One way to write the code in clear steps is to increase the variable, then make sure that it's in the range 0..9, and finally display the value. That makes it easy to follow what's happening to the value:

```
int szám = 0;
private void counterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    szám++;
    szám %= 10;
    this.Text = szám.ToString();
}
```

You can of course write that as an `if` statement if you like:

```
int szám = 0;
private void counterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    szám++;
    if (szám == 10) {
      szám = 0;
    }
    this.Text = szám.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is ok. But there are always other ways to get the same result which may be more elegant.

```
private void counterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    szám=(szám +1) % 10;
    this.Text = szám.ToString();
}
```

or you can do:

```
private void counterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    szám=(9==szám)?0:szám+1;
    this.Text = szám.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a problem with the -1? why is it less elegent than use an if statement with 0?

Comment: There is no problem with your `-1` way. It is only more lines of code and a little bit unusual. No Problem as long as your `szám` is a signed variable.

Comment: There is no good reason to write [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) in C#. Just write `szám == 9`, it's more readable.

Comment: @svick: That is just a matter of different tastes. I like Yoda conditions and am used to read them. And they are still useful. E.g. `"Hello".Equals(input)` can never throw an NullReferenceException, but `input.Equals("hello")` can.

Comment: @MrSmith42 `input == "hello"` also never throws and works just as well. (Many types that have `Equals()` also have `==`.) As an alternative, you could write `object.Equals(input, "Hello")`.

Comment: I think, the first option is the best you can do with C#.

Comment: @svick: what if `input` is `null` than `input.Equals("hello")` should throw the Exception.